# Eloquent mass assignment from multi-dimentional array along with model relationships

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5, eloquent, mass-assignment

I've got a multidimensional array coming from `$_POST`. Its keys are exactly the same as either columns in the `blog_posts` table or names of its relations (e.g. `author`).

I would like to mass assign the $_POST to a matching object and its relations. Example:

```
$_POST = array (
    'blog_post' => array (
        'title' => 'the title of the post',
        'content' => 'the content of the post',
        'date' => '23-09-2015',
        'author' => array (
            'name' => 'hydra',
            'age' => 47,
            'location' => 'Russia',
        ),
    ),
);
```

would be mapped to a `blog_post` object and a `author` object.

2 things to keep in mind:

- this is only an example, i've no clue what type of objects i'll be working with;
- the solution should also be usable with collections of objects

my current (obviously non-working) solution would involve:

```
array_walk($_POST, function(value, key){
    if (is_array($value) && class_exists($key)) {
        $object = new $key($value);
        $object->save();
    }
});
```

This only saves the first object (`blog_post`).

Edit: security is not my concern at the moment, i will be sanitizing $_POST before inserting, but the main issue is mass assignment without having to know which class i'm using and assigning relationships by hand.

Comment: i (obviously) tried `$blog_post = new blog_post($_POST['blog_post']); $blog_post->save();` This doesn't save the `author` too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are missing the relationship between `blog_post` and `author`. If you have a relationship defined, you won't be able to save `author` because it will be missing a required foreign key.

This might work:

```
$parent = null;
array_walk($_POST, function(value, key){
 if (is_array($value) && class_exists($key)) {
    $object = new $key($value);
    if(!empty($parent)){
     $parent->$key()->save($object); // function author(){$this->hasOne('author');} on blog_post model
    }
    else{
     $object->save();
    }
    $parent = $object;
 }
});
```

Comment: all relationships between models have been defined and the structure of the `$_POST` array conforms with those relations.

Comment: that is why your code is not able to save `author` because it is missing the foreign key when you do `$object->save()` on `author`. The above code `$parent->$key()->save($object)` should work if your `$_POST` array confirms to the relationship.

Comment: all relationships are working properly, i can do `$blog_post->author->save()`. that is not the issue here, i'm trying to mass assign relationships.